# How to localize the text strings in Outlook web addin manifest file

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I have developed an Outlook Web Addin. There are couple of strings in web addin manifest file. Is there a way to use localized resource strings in the manifest file. The example of the strings is given as follows :

```
    <bt:Urls>
     
      <bt:Url id="msgReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:5000/" />
    </bt:Urls>
    <bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group" />
      <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab" />
      <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="My Outlook Web Addin" />
      <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Save Email to External Repository" />
    </bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:LongStrings>
      <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="This plugin allows you to save your emails and attachments to an external repository. It has been developed by AR" />
    </bt:LongStrings>
  </Resources>
```

I need to localize the strings with "paneReadSuperTipTitle" and "paneReadSuperTipDescription" ids. Can you help me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control localization from the manifest by overriding the defaultLocale. Documentation about how to override, set a locale, and specify localized values from the manifest can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/localization#control-localization-from-the-manifest).

There is an example in our documentation of how to specify a localized string values [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/resources#resources-examples) as well.

Comment: As per the documentation, you can use override for 1 additional language. what if you want to support more than one language?